# Laravel 5.7 - Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, checkbox, offset, laravel-5.7

I'm new in Laravel and it is my first question.
I have 3 tables:

categories: id, name (at the moment 2 items)

variants: id, name

category_variant: id, category_id, variant_id; <--
Every variant has 1 or 2 categories

In the VariantController I have following code:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $variant = Variant::where('id', $id)->with('categories')->first();
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('admin.variant.edit', compact('variant', 'categories'));
}
```

In the edit.blade.php I have following html:

```html
@foreach ($categories as $key=>$category)
   <div class="form-group form-float">
   @if (isset($variant->categories[$key]->pivot->category_id)) <-- I think here is the problem
      <input type="checkbox" id="wb" class="filled-in" name="wb" value="{{$category->id}}" {{ $category->id == $variant->categories[$key]->pivot->category_id  ? 'checked' : ''}} >
      <label for="wb">{{ $category->name}}</label>
   @else
      <input type="checkbox" id="wb" class="filled-in" name="wb" value="{{$category->id}}">
      <label for="wb">{{ $category->name}}</label>
   @endif
   </div>
@endforeach
```

I want to know which category was checked in the checkbox. If the variant has all 2 categories everthing is ok but if the user has chosen only one category I get an error

```
Undefined offset: 1 (View: /shui/resources/views/admin/variant/edit.blade.php)
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance
Dimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the power of [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-contains):

```
@if($variant->categories->contains($category))
    {{--  You does not need to test a second time to know if you need to "check" --}}
    <input type="checkbox" id="wb" class="filled-in" name="wb" value="{{$category->id}}" checked >
    <label for="wb">{{ $category->name}}</label>
@else
    {{-- Do stuff --}}
@endif
```

Or simpler. Remove the first `@if`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="wb" class="filled-in" name="wb" value="{{$category->id}}" $variant->categories->contains($category)? 'checked' : '' >
<label for="wb">{{ $category->name}}</label>
```

---

Also in you Controller, you can simplify

```
$variant = Variant::where('id', $id)->with('categories')->first();
```

with

```
$variant = Variant::with('categories')->find($id);
// Or better, Laravel throws a 404 error when the id doesn't exists
$variant = Variant::with('categories')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: Dear cbaconnier, thank you very much for your answer. It's works fine. Dimi